# Add pagination to search.php page

Tags: pages, pagination, search, 404-error, links

When I want to use the_posts_pagination() in my search.php page and I click "2" or "3", it goes on 404 page (this link: mywebsite/page/2/?s=a). How can I add pagination for search.php page?

**SOLVED**

It didn't work because of the query_posts() inside search.php .

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Would you mind clarifying? I am having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes pagination will break and give unexpected results, redirect you to the wrong page or give you a 404 (page not found) on the "paged" pages. This is usually due to your theme altering (querying) the main loop wrong.

Try updating your .htaccess file by updating the permalink.